# Tpl system doesn't actually parse params into value

Tags: php, parameters

So for my graduation project I chose to make my own template engine, instead of using something like rain, or smarty. Now I'm at the params part, but every time I run the script, it doesn't actually parse the variables...

Take a look at my parameter parse function:

```
public function parseParameters()
{
    if ( isset ( $this->parameter ) )
    {
        foreach ($this->parameter as $key => $value) {
            str_replace( $this->content, '{' . $key . '}', $value );
        }
    }

    if ( isset ( $this->langParameters ) )
    {
        foreach ($this->langParameters as $key => $value) {
            str_replace( $this->content, '{$' . $key . '}', $value );
        }
    }

    if ( isset ( $this->templateData ) )
    {
        foreach ($this->templateData as $key => $value) {
            str_replace( $this->content, '{#' . $key . '}', $value );
        }
    }

    echo $this->content;
}
```

I chose a `foreach loop` over my old `array_keys` solution. But it clearly doesn't work...

Some more information:

Yes, the `$this->content` variable is defined.

This is how I set the parameters:

```
public function createParameter( $key, $value )
{
    $this->parameter[ $key ] = $value;
}
```

Exactly the same for the other two types of parameters, only with different names.

If you need any more code, please say so.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

what's the $this->content?? is the string in which you want to replace `"{$key}"` with `$value`?? Then its should be last argument. AND `str_replace` function returns the replaced string only, doesn't change in third argument. So:

```
 $this->content = str_replace('{' . $key . '}', $value,  $this->content );
```

**Documentation:** [PHP: str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

Comment: It gives the same result. Also, the `$this->content` is the page where the params are.

Comment: @W.H.E.Peeters Means in `content` variable params are there, and those are same as `$key`. Then you need debugging. **echo `$this->content` and see what is the format of params there.** Is it `{varName}` OR `{$varName}` OR `{ varName }` any spaces etc OR `$varName` without braces?? Then write the first argument of `str_replace` accordingly. _Ex: `str_replace("\$$key", $value, $this->content);` for last case._

Comment: @Adarash Rajput It does output `{key}` I'm already echoing, the brackets with the dollar sign are for the language params, and the one with the hashtag is template related stuff that comes from the database, like page titles and stuff.

Comment: @W.H.E.Peeters **Sorry!** I forgot one thing, `str_replace` dose not replace in argument, it returns the replaced string so code should be: **`$this->content = str_replace('{' . $key . '}', $value,  $this->content );`**. You cant believe that same error I got in my project twice, today and at same time I was answering you... :P

Answer (score -1):

I use a similar template engine, and i encountered (some time) similar problems... are you sure that the values that you are replacing are strings? If not cast them as strings.

```
if ( isset ( $this->parameter ) )
{
    foreach ($this->parameter as $key => $value) {
        str_replace('{' . $key . '}', (string)$value,  $this->content);
    }
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Nothing... The variable params are still unparsed.